# Flutter show to split very long text and show by dividing?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am migrating my ionic app to flutter i have some data which need to split and show.
The string look like this `PRE-AUTHORIZATION=MANDATORY AT NON-PANEL HOSPITALS|||||HOSPITAL NETWORK=220+ FACILITIES NATIONWIDE|||||`
I need to break the line when ||||| this come split the word on =

The code in typescript look something like this

```
  const policies = this.wording.split('|').filter(w => w !== '');
  this.displayData = [];
  policies.forEach((policy) => {
    const splited = policy.split('=');
    const displayPolicy = {name: splited[0], value: splited[1]};
    this.displayData.push(displayPolicy);
  });
```

In app the string look like this
[image]

Any one please tell how can i show this data in flutter app same like in image Thanks

This is my full code i am using

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';

class BenefitScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BenefitScreenState createState() => _BenefitScreenState();
}

class _BenefitScreenState extends State<BenefitScreen> {

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    doSomeAsyncStuff();
  }

  Future<String> doSomeAsyncStuff() async {
    final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
    String value = await storage.read(key: 'company_id');
    print(value);

    String url2 =
        'gttps://api?company_id=${value}';

    final response2 = await http.get(url2);
    var Data = json.decode(response2.body);
    print(Data);
    print(Data["records"][0]["policies"][0]["policywording"]);
    var DisplayData = Data["records"][0]["policies"][0]["policywording"]; // This is the data which need to split 

    return DisplayData;
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('IGI GENERAL INSURANCE'),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: doSomeAsyncStuff(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              print(snapshot.data);
              return  Text('Here in ned to show data');

            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'),
              );
            } else {
              return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                child: Text('Awaiting result...'),
              );
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

And there is one more thing all string not contain = sign to split. i have attached the image as you can see first value dont have have = sign and its showing in blue text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in typescript can be converted to following method:

```
List<Map<String, String>> divideString(String wording) {
  final policies = wording.split('|').where((w) => w != '');
  var displayData = <Map<String, String>>[];
  policies.forEach((policy) {
    final splitted = policy.split('=');
    final displayPolicy = <String, String>{
      'name': splitted[0],
      'value': splitted.length > 1 ? splitted[1] : null,
    };
    displayData.add(displayPolicy);
  });

  return displayData;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but its showing this error Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1 If i remove the 'value': splited[1] its working fine but when i add this its showing the error. I think its because every workding dont have = sign and it breaks ? Any solution for this

Comment: I fixed the code. I didn't notice the note about strings without equal sign.

Comment: thanks you so much can you little define this splited.length > 1 ? splited[1] : null i dint understand

Comment: If you split value by `=` and there is no equal sign in a string, then length of `splitted` is 1 (because there is nothing to split, so the only value is the string from `policy` variable), thus you can't reach element on second position (with index `[1]`) and you set `null` instead of string after `=`. If the length is greater than 1 (so there is `=` sign in the string), you use the value after `=` by getting value on second position in `splitted` variable by using index `[1]`. 

`condition ? if_true : if_false` is widely known as ternary operator.